# Difference between machine language and machine code, maybe in the C64 community?

Tags: commodore-64, programming, assembly, terminology, machine-code

I've always been sure that "machine language" and "machine code" are totally synonymous and mean programming directly in the language the machine understands, whether in binary, hex, or decimal; whether using some kind of hex editor or a BASIC loader with a POKE loop and DATA statements.

These two were opposed to "assembly language" which means programming in text mnemonics that a program called an "assembler" converted into the numbers the machine would understand; whether compiling directly into RAM, producing an object file that needed linking, or producing an executable file.

But I've just watched a good YouTube video on retrocomputing channel 8-Bit Show And Tell called ['"Hello World" on Commodore 64 in Assembly Language, Machine Code'](https://youtu.be/CHLzzfEmj3I).

It's a good video for anyone into retrocomputing who didn't do programming back in the day or only programmed BASIC.

But he demonstrates three ways to program. One he calls "assembly language", one "machine language", and another "machine code".

I'd never heard of anyone differentiating those last two before. Was this a widespread view among programmers? Just among 6502 programmers? Just among C64 programmers? Something that some people used to do in the 8-bit days that nobody does anymore? Maybe it's an accepted difference everybody uses that I alone missed?

Here's the relevant parts of the content creator's notes in the video's chapter index:

> - [5:48](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHLzzfEmj3I&t=348s) Assembly Language with TMP
> - [16:20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHLzzfEmj3I&t=980s) Machine Language with SuperMon 64
> - [23:19](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHLzzfEmj3I&t=1399s) Machine Code with BASIC loader

I Googled these terms: "TMP" is Turbo Macro Pro, an assembler for the Commodore 64. "Supermon64" is a machine-language monitor for the Commodore 64.

His clearest definition of the contrast between the three terms seems to be in the intro to the "Machine code with BASIC loader" section:

> Okay so we've looked at Assembly Language and Turbo Macro Pro we've
> looked at what we might call machine language in supermon and
> now well yeah basically the lowest level is what we might call
> machine code which is just programming and hex bytes

In the part he considers "machine language" but not "machine code" he's using the C64 monitor "Supermon64" in which he enters MOS opcodes and the monitor converts that opcode to hex bytes. I would consider this to be programming in assembly language. But I never had such a tool back in the day.

In a response to my comment on the video, the author clarified thusly:

> when authors (or speakers) use both terms with intention, there's
> definitely a trend to using "machine language" to mean the mnemonic
> representation and "machine code" to mean the numeric/hex
> representation. The term "code" comes from the cryptic numbers that
> represent the machine instructions

Interestingly, "machine language" was favoured [in the US while](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=machine%20code%2Cmachine%20language&year_start=1939&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=0) while "machine code" was favoured [in the UK](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=machine%20code%2Cmachine%20language&year_start=1939&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=0). In both cases by a factor of two, and both peaked about 1985.

Comment: So what are these three different demonstrated methods then, or the difference between the two? Imagine the video does not exist forever so please make the question standalone.

Comment: @Justme: Done. Let me know if it's not good enough.

Comment: An assembler typically includes labels and equates and allows them to be referenced in instructions and directives. Perhaps they mean machine language as using mnemonic instructions but without labels?

Comment: @ecm I guess that's what he means. Is that the common understanding? It's funny that many times when I told people I used to program in machine code/machine language they told me that I was really programming in assembly language even though I was hand-assembling (-: Maybe this question is equivalent in some way to what is and is not an assembler. I used to write disassemblers for Z80 and m68k and from what I know of 6502, it's so simple that you wouldn't need much logic to translate opcodes to machine code in comparison to Z80 and m68k. Would that make it "not assembling" though?

Comment: On the topic of what would and wouldn't qualify as an assembler, there's useful info in the comments right through our thread at [How was the first assembler for a new home computer platform written?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3326)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no (ISO or other) standard defining these terms. I'm afraid that the understanding depends not really on the community, but on the group of persons talking to each other. As such, this question might not be answerable satisfyingly.

Comment: In my experience, there is no consistent use of those terms; different people use it differently. So I don't think you'll find any universally accepted definition anywhere.

Comment: You might also want to research the terminology associated with DDT for the PDP-1 computer in the early 1960s.  DDT had the instruction code mnemonics built in, and it was possible to enter machine instructions directly without preparing a source program in assembler language.   This was typically done only for very small projects.

Comment: 'machine code' is where the actual binary is on the paper tape.  It's not something I'd use, but I'd say that 'machine language' might be where there was a representation of machine code in characters (strings of digits, possibly separated into fields) on the paper tape,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That video probably tries to add a bit too much definition into blurry terminology, at least my opinion.

In fact, all three ways he describes are ways of creating machine code, and, at the same time, programming in assembly - He just uses different tools.

Classically, people used the term *machine code* to denote inputting hex (or, more rarely, decimal or octal) binary representations into a computer to generate programs. In order to determine what bytes make up the program, they would have used an *assembler* to make sense what the instructions actually are.

Here, it doesn't really make a difference whether you make up the instructions in your head, on paper, or in a text file that's run through a program - Somehow, everyone building a machine code program tends to **think** in assembly language, whether the actual translation takes place in a computer (the "assembler") or in your head doesn't make much of a difference (the latter one simply takes up more calories...).  While I still remember that "0c9h" is "ret" on a Z80 and will probably never forget, most of the other opcode-to-instruction translations were forgotten once I used assemblers regularly - and is probably useless knowledge today anyhow. More complicated Z80 instructions (like *LD A, (IX+7)*, for example), I never even tried to "head-assemble".

So, in my mind, you're always programming in assembly, regardless of whether you use your in-built (gray-matter), notes on paper, a machine code monitor, or an external (silicon-based) assembler. If you're simply inputting hex numbers from somewhere, well you're not programming.

**Unless** you're doing very weird stuff like self-modifying code (somewhat low on that scale, at least on 8-bit CPUs) or jumping into the middle of another multibyte instruction to have the CPU re-interpret already existing code (pretty much top of weirdness scale). These "dirty tricks" would be very much discouraged today and would probably be considered rather a "puzzle than a program" because they lead to heavily un-readable code. Back in the day, they were, however, relatively more common. But even then, you would have **thought** in assembly, and rather have the opcodes as a second thought "overlay".

Comment: I'm going to guess `ld a, (ix+7)` is `0ddh 07eh 007h`.

Comment: @Neil I'm going to guess: You cheated ;)

Comment: Sadly when I was a kid I used to hand assemble large programs which I would run on my ZX81 and later ZX Spectrum, so no cheating necessary. I eventually wrote my own assembler, although obviously did I have to assemble it by hand first...

Comment: @Neil Nothing sad about that, that's real nerd cred! I wrote numerous disassemblers on my Speccy but always in BASIC and never wrote a disassembler. Of course I never had any storage other than cassette tape so every crash was s.l.o.w.

Comment: @hippietrail Ironically my assembler worked by replacing and extending the Spectrum's own BASIC interpreter. You even had to write your own `FOR` loop around the assembly to make two passes to fix up forward jumps!

Comment: LDDR and LDIR is CD B0 and CD B1, iirc. Or vice versa. :-D

Comment: As someone who's written multiple code-golf answers in x86 machine code, yes, most of them were just a matter of thinking in assembly and optimizing for code-size (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30206/peter-cordes?tab=answers) - knowing instruction lengths is way easier than knowing the hex value of every opcode.  A few involved lower level tricks like the opcode for `cmp al, imm8` to consume the first byte of a loop without executing it on the first iteration, but that's still thinking in asm.  Only a few restricted-source questions made me look through opcode tables, IIRC.

Comment: [Hell0 W0rld! scored by ASCII values](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194665) was scored based on the byte values of the machine code (since that's the "language" I answered in), so that was a case of thinking about the byte values while making programming choices.   [Determine your language's version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139717) involved knowing how stuff decoded in different modes, and [Find an Illegal String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133622) required knowing about instruction-encoding details.

Comment: I think anyone who has programmed machine language/code or assembly and has also written a disassembler probably thinks at least partly in bit patterns since you have to delve into those to write instruction and addressing mode decoders. Probably the same goes to a lesser degree for an assembler but I never wrote one.

Answer (score 13):

An assembler actually does *two* important but separate things to help the programmer. One, which you mentioned, is to convert instruction mnemonics into opcodes, based on the addressing mode (e.g., `LDA #3` to `A9 03` or `LDA $1005` to `AD 05 10`—note the different opcodes for loading an immediate value versus loading a value from a memory address).

But the other, which actually saves a lot more work, is to assign addresses to code and data and do address calculations based on those assignments. So in the following example:

```
        ORG $1000

        LDX #$FF
loop:   STX myvar
        DEX
        BNE loop
        RTS

myvar   DB  $00
```

the assembler is calculating the addresses which the programmer refers to as `loop` and `myvar`, so that the programmer doesn't have to do this himself. In this example, `loop` will be at $1002 and `myvar` will be at $100A, but both of those would change if the programmer added another instruction between the start of the program and `loop`. Further, some of the calculations are not as easy to do as the one above: the `BNE loop` is translated to `D0 FA` where the `FA` is a negative offset from the start of the location after the `BNE` and its argument.

So 8-Bit Show And Tell making a distinction between:

- assembly: computer-calculation of addresses and opcodes (`STX myvar`);
- machine language: hand-calculation of addresses with mnemonic translation (`STX $100A`); and
- machine code: hand-calculation of addresses and opcodes (`8E 0A 10`).

Because this three-part distinction isn't so often made, many people use "machine language or machine code" interchangeably for the last one, or perhaps either of the two. The middle one is sometimes referred to as a form of "assembly": on the Apple II with original ROMs, for example, you use the "mini-assembler" for that. Given what 8-Bit Show and Tell is trying to demonstrate, I find his terms reasonable; he just would have done better to explain that when using a "full" assembler, it's not the mnemonic translation that (though useful) is the most important thing, but the address assignments and calculations.

Comment: I've definitely heard the term "symbolic assembler" which makes it seem like that was an improvement over previous assemblers at some point? I suppose the next advance after that would've been the "macro assembler", which is surely a more common term. True though when I used to hand assemble Z80 code, getting the offsets right hurt my head in a way opcodes never did.

Comment: @hippietrail Yes, I've heard the term "symbolic assembler," too, implying that earlier there were "non-symbolic" assemblers. But by the 1970s no serious developer would have accepted an assembler that did not equate labels and addresses and do address calculations; it would have been very little improvement over programming directly in machine code.

Comment: I've got a moderate amount of experience programming directly in machine code on 6502 and 6800, and as you start working with things like `A9 03` versus `AD 0A 10` you fairly quickly memorise the opcodes for the various different addressing modes for the instructions you commonly use; it's the address calculations that really are most of the work.

Comment: I'm guessing there was a time where monitors that could assemble single opcodes and addressing modes like the one he uses on the C64 and like I think the one in the Apple 2 ROM might've been able to do, were a/the common kind of assembly tool. I moved away from the Apple 2 before I knew about the monitor or assembly or machine code and the TRS-80 model 1 and 3, and the Speccy didn't have such a feature. My first assembler was on the Amiga 2000 in maybe 1992 and was a full macro assembler of course.

Comment: @hippietrail yes, symbolic assemblers were an important step, but it was as well a step already taken with the very first what assemblers that lifted programming from code. Regarding micros, it may help to remember that their development happened _after_ the assembler word was already way past those baby steps.

Comment: Symbolic assemblers also helped cleaning up code: Without them, you would really hesitate inserting or deleting code somewhere and having to go through the chore of re-calculating all jump targets - You'd rather patch some jump to the end, place your extension code there and jump back.

Comment: Of course, the thing that eventually blew me away was a symbolic debugger. We eventually got a Z-80 In-Circuit Emulator with a floppy drive. You could put a MAP file on the drive and suddenly you were within a century of a modern debugger. It was as big a step as going to a symbolic assembler

Comment: I did some 1802 development using a simple assembler I cobbled together which didn't process any mnemonics for instructions, but accepted input as a list of hex bytes interspersed with symbol definition, reference markers, and a couple of "set address" and "add to address" directives.  Tiny little thing that took almost no time to write, but worked quite nicely given the regularity of the instruction set.

Answer (score 5):

### Short Answer:

He 'adapts' his own terms to distinguish between the different 'styles' of programming he wants to show in this video.

---

### Long Answer:

#### There is No Simple Answer

Well, as so often in real life terms are used overlapping and interchangeable depending on point of view as well as on upbringing, meaning what terms one was exposed to first (*1). Any answer will thus have a hard stand to provide definitive guidelines. Even more when, like here, terms are crafted in a way to bring forth the narrative of different levels of low level programming.

But what can be done is taking a step back and look at the logic behind terms used *and* their relation:

#### Look at the Beautiful Words

- **Machine**

  Back when computers were devices of sensible size Machine was an all encompassing term without much separation between parts. What historical and in this context is a machine is nowadays rather called a CPU.
- **Assembler**

  An Assembler is a generic term for a tool to write programs with high control over the resulting binary. Like most tools it needs as input information about what it has to create, plus directions how to do it.

  For the definition of an Assembler it does not matter how comfortable it supports program generation but only that it does not act on code level.
- **Code**

  The (more or less) binary representation of what a CPU (should) execute. No matter if human readable or not.

#### One and a Half More:

To complete the list and look at the relations, we may have to add another term:

- **Instruction Set**

  The collection of all instructions a given CPU can execute ('understand').

The instruction set may be the single most important term here, as it's what all this is about, all the other set the stage to debate the instruction set.

An instruction set is CPU specific and documented in an often big manual. Each instruction initiates some workings and is (usually) named accordingly. Let's take the beautiful /370 instruction `Compare Double and Swap` a staple in concurrent programming. While the name is mostly self explanatory, and a one on one relation to what the CPU can do, it's rather unwieldy in common use, so a very important *intermediate step* is added:

- **Mnemonics**

  Instead of saying `Compare Double and Swap`, `CDS` can be used as a more compact term.

Sounds at first like a big word for what otherwise is known as an abbreviation to step down from lengthy word clouds to short synonyms - except, it wasn't developed as such, but the other way around: As a step up to name code items (in this case `X'BB'`) in an easy to memorize way. Coming from Greek `Mnemonika` for (human) memory.

#### It's Full of Stars

With above terms one can easy see that in everyday language a lot of overlapping usage can be found - all depending what to say.

For a more exact usage one can go along a few guiderails:

- **Assembly Language** per se does not exist.

It is, for the ISA part, always tied to a specific CPU with its specific instruction set and (usual) specific syntax - no matter if an assembler is made for a single CPU or multiple or configurable.

In addition the directives how to build a program with and beside the ISA are specific to the tool (Assembler) used. E.g. NASM and MASM as x86 assembler understand the same ISA but are not 1:1 compatible by differing how x86 instructions are controlled.

For being an assembler and thus assembler language it doesn't matter how great this additional support is or how much the programmer has to do on his own.

- Machine Language is a sloppy every day term and usually used interchangeable with assembler language. It
- Machine Code is when raw instruction representation is handled - by CPU or human.

So in the end, the language as well as the machine part in either terms are redundant - including their combination.

---

### The Details

> [...] he's using the C64 monitor "Supermon64" [...] I would consider this to be programming in assembly language.

Well, it is, and he even calls it so - right 9 seconds before your second link at [971](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHLzzfEmj3I&t=971s):

*"Now we can write our machine language program. And there is a simple **assembler**, non symbolic it's called, [...]. So we're going to **assemble** ..." followed by him entering the command `A` for assemble.*

So he's very much is aware that he is using an assembler.

After all, noone would call Wozniak's [Mini-Assembler](https://www.callapple.org/vintage-apple-computers/apple-ii/apple-mini-assembler/) for the Apple II anything other than an assembler - despite being even less confortable than Supermon's `A` command.

> "when authors (or speakers) use both terms with intention, there's definitely a trend to using "machine language" to mean the mnemonic representation and "machine code" to mean the numeric/hex representation."

Which in turn would mean that machine language is the same as assembly language.

> "The term "code" comes from the cryptic numbers that represent the machine instructions"

Code is a term used for any kind of formal, non casual information. No matter if it's about how pilots communicate or every generation creates their own youth language. Beside those numbers are not more cryptic to the general public than mnemonics - and not cryptic at all to anyone doing low level programming.

---

*1 - One may not go into a rant about home grown terms in the C64 community - except it wouldn't help any further  for this.