# What does it mean to "publish machine code"?

Tags: history, terminology, microsoft-basic, machine-code

The [Wikipedia article on “An Open Letter to Hobbysts”](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=An_Open_Letter_to_Hobbyists&oldid=1177983526) says that Bill Gates complained about hobbyists pirating his software, and due to piracy he refused to publish the machine code of his Altair BASIC.

The Wikipedia article states:

> He cited the unfairness of gaining the benefits of software authors' time, effort, and capital without paying them as a rationale for refusing to publish the machine code for his company's flagship product, thereby making it available to lower-income hobbyists who could have borrowed such program listings from their local library and entered the program into their hobby computer by data entry.

1. What does it mean to publish the machine code?
2. Why programmers used to publish machine code?

Comment: The phrase "machine code" doesn't appear in the actual [letter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Open_Letter_to_Hobbyists#/media/File%3ABill_Gates_Letter_to_Hobbyists_ocr.pdf).  In fact I don't see anything about refusing to publish code of any kind.  It seems to me that [this insertion by an anonymous Wikipedia user at 70.171.155.43](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=An_Open_Letter_to_Hobbyists&diff=prev&oldid=1007123660) is inaccurate as well as poorly worded.

Comment: I have reverted that edit and deleted the passage in question.

Comment: Other than that it happened a while back, how is this about Retrocomputing at all, let alone compared to copyright, intellectual property or publishing in general?

My suggestion is that except historically, this Question has nothing to do with retrocomputing.

Either way, are you suggesting there's something special about publishing machine code, as compared to publishing anything else?

Comment: I remember typing in pages of hex into a Commodore-64 from the back of magazines with a friend. One of us would read, the other would type, and at the end, we had a new game saved on tape.

Comment: @NateEldredge I suggest converting that into an answer, since "the passage didn't appear in the cited text" is clearly the correct one.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The question is about history and terminology not about the copyright and IP issues that just happen to be the context in which the terminology was found.

Comment: @Mark Morgan Lloyd the question is "what does it mean to publish machine code", not whether Bill Gates wanted to publish any particular machine code of any particular software

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin I have never heard about "publishing machine code" as a means to distribute a software. Do you have some examples of a software distributed by publishing its machine code in printed form in the last 10 years?

Comment: Why are you asking about paper, for Goodness' sake? To go right back to basics - because clearly, it's vital here - what does 'publish' mean to you?

What could 'publishing machine code' mean, except a means to distribute software?

Come to that was 'a software' simply a typo, or a problem with English?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What does it mean to publish the machine code?

Machine Code in the sense used is what otherwise would be called a **HEX-Listing** or **HEX-Dump**. The most compact form a program could be published and distributed - it was the time before one could just download a file or walk to your local computer store (or Walmart) to buy some media with that file. Not to mention that a good number of users did not have any peripherals.

Machine code listings are the earliest form of 'binary' software distribution, no matter if printed in a magazine or as punch tape (*1).

> Why programmers used to publish machine code?

It's less about programmers as magazines managing their pages. While it's no issue to have a page or two of assembly source (or BASIC or PASCAL), anything past the most simple application would take a whole book.

Just take the BASIC in question. Micro Soft's [1978 6502 version](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=774) consisted of 6,955 lines (*4) of source code. Printed in a magazine this will fill a good **100 pages** (*5).

In contrast Intel-Hex printed as two columns at 70 lines will 'store' 2.2 KiB per page, so an 8 KiB Basic can fit on **4 pages** including some headers and explanation.

---

#### So, why does Mr. Gates refer to this at all?

At the time it was common to circulate software as Hex-Listing either in paper tape form, or as print out. Hobbyists shared their programs that way on their meetings. Mr. Gates is directly referring to this practice which of course would undermine his sales.

---

*1 - Punch tape based software distribution was usually not made using binary encoding but as loadable tape according to a CPU manufacturer format like [Intel-Hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) (*2,*3), [Motorola S-Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_(file_format)) or [MOS' format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_file_format), or computer manufacturer format like [Extended Tektronix Hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tektronix_hex_format).

*2 - Like [Tiny-BASIC](https://www.autometer.de/unix4fun/z80pack/ftp/altair/tinybasic-2.0.hex) was distributed

*3 - Extended by several companies, like Zilog, and used until today - even for brand new systems like the BBC MicroBit with its 'Universal Hex Format'

*4 - Byte used for Assembly listings an extended [satzspiegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canons_of_page_construction) of ~70 lines per page - almost too small to read.

*5 - An impractical amount, even for a magazine like Byte. Its 1/1978 issue had less than 200 pages with a good 50+% being advertisement.

Comment: So programmers would actually go through the trouble of _typing_ pages and pages of machine code into their machine? Amazing how much time people had before the internet stole it away...

Comment: @leftaroundabout No they didn't. Typing in a page or two of machine code was possible - I did it once or twice - but typing in a whole BASIC interpreter would have been extremely time consuming. Serious software for the computer we had (a Commodore PET) was distributed on cassette tape or floppy disk.

Comment: @leftaroundabout yes, they did - of course in varying degree. Keep in mind, these were the very early times with only a few people involved,usually very dedicated ones.

Comment: @JeremyP as shown, two pages of machine code is already 4.5 KiB, quite enough for a BASIC interpreter. The PET having a cassette is already a step forward, the Altair wasn't delivered with one and it needed later, 3rd party boards to add one. Also, typing in many pages of hex code was even a thing 10 years later for C64 et. al. As mentioned, going to the next store isn't always possible. To start with, it depends on having a reachable store.

Comment: Weren't there also magazines that published barcode of programs? They could be loaded into computers similar to loading cassettes.

Comment: @Barmar yes, there were all kind of variants to use printout to transport data. Barcodes happened in the early 1980s and again in the 1990. So many years after 1976. (And today again with QR-Codes)

Comment: @Raffzahn It's all "way back then" to me :). Now this has reminded me of the RSA T-shirt, which has since been remade using QR-code.

Comment: "We" (well, certainly I) typed is legion amounts of code. TIme and labor I had, money for tapes and such, not so much. Assembly was difficult simply because if it went wrong, you were kind of dead in the water. It was difficult for novices to debug compared to BASIC. My friend and I took turns typing in the FigForth PDP source on the schools PDP-11/70. There's a reason why many of the magazines offered utilities to help you ensure that you were typing in code correctly (typically checksums for each line). In consumer magazines, assembly was rare, but not in magazines like Dr. Dobbs.

Comment: *"Machine code listings are the earliest form of 'binary' software distribution"* -- within the narrow context of hobbyist computing.  Earlier than that (an old man writes) we at least got our compilers on paper tape.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: [Type-in programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-in_program) were more commonly written in BASIC than in machine code.  Though, some of these programs (targeted at specific computers) included simple machine-language routines that were specified in BASIC `DATA` statements.

Comment: Note that Microsoft BASIC was pretty much the first ever commercial "shrinkwrap" software.  Before then, you had operating systems that came with the (mainframe or mini) computer, and internal (or consultingware) software that was customized for one company's needs and couldn't usefully be redistributed elsewhere.  The idea of a third party writing a program to be installed on thousands/millions of computers was new, and it wasn't well-known how copyright law would apply.

Comment: As I noted above, Gates's letter didn't actually say or refer to any of this.  OP's quoted text is an inaccurate summary by an anonymous Wikipedia editor, which I have since removed.

Answer (score 4):

In 1976, there was a lot more software, especially for microcomputers, written directly in assembly language. The BASIC interpreter certainly was written in assembly language. At the time, the term "machine code" referred to the textual representation of the program that would be assembled into the final product.

Today the name we use for this "machine code" is "source code". So, Gates is referring to his reluctance to publish the source code for his BASIC interpreter.

Comment: Microcomputer users might have called their assembly-language programs "machine code", but none of the minicomputer people I associated with did that.  Mostly machine code lived on machine-readable storage, but if it was on paper, it'd be a string of octal.

Comment: I still like to distinguish assembler from machine code. Back in the days gone by when I first got involved and had no assembler it was raw machine code, although I would write  instructions e.g. jmp but to actually code then it was the hex of the opcode and then where to jump as the hex code. Pretty slow work. Got an assembler  much faster coding and letting the assembler produce the machine code.

Comment: I PEEKed out the whole of the ZX80 ROM as decimal, writing it all out manually as hex, then converted to Z80 assembler by looking up every instruction in a book. Not made easier by not knowing which bytes were code, data, or memory-mapped devices. I made reasonable sense out of some parts of it. Never again!

Comment: Is there a citation for "machine code" being conventionally used to refer to assembler source code?

Comment: @another-dave there are definitely endless examples of that conflation e.g. [here](https://worldofspectrum.org/archive/magazines/pages/your-spectrum/1/19) or [here](https://archive.org/details/masteringmachinecodeonyourzx81) — though many other contemporaneous sources (such as [this](https://archive.org/details/mc-graw-hill-oric-atmos-and-oric-1-graphics-and-machine-code-techniques/page/26/mode/2up)) are more careful.

Comment: ... and, as an aside, noting that — *very* anecdotally — 'machine language' also seemed to crop up quite a lot in the 8-bit hobbyist sources I checked quickly just now, usually meaning assembly language but sometimes meaning machine code.

Comment: @Tommy - the first link (Your Spectrum) seems to contradict you, since the columns 'machine code' and 'assembler' are clearly distinct. There is one use of 'machine code' in the text, but it refers to '18FE LOOP JMP LOOP' so I don't think it's definitive.  Similarly, the second (ZX81 book) contains a chapter 'intro to hexadecimal and machine code', so it doesn't seem to be talking about assembler either.

Comment: @another-dave texts are "Consider the machine code program: 18FE LOOP JR LOOP"; "In machine language we assign variables (registers) using the instruction LD". Please explain your statement that this contradicts my claim of **a conflation**.

Comment: @another-dave: Note that the machine code representation for "LOOP JR LOOP" would be the bit pattern represented by the hex constants "18 FE".  It was more common for computers to have a utiltiy to show a human-readable version of whatever machine code was in memory than a bona fide assembler.

Comment: [A few months ago I discovered that some even distinguish "assembly language" vs "machine language" vs "machine code".](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27284) A lot of terminology that's now set turns out to have been more variable back in the early days. I know we've turned up surprises in the terms for assembling vs compiling here before.

Comment: Note that at the time and later, it was actually common to publish FOSS as "machine code" as printed hex characters on paper. Which a hobbiest, with more time than money, could laboriously enter, one character at a time, and build.